# How can I combine these two imagemagick convert commands?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

How can I combine the following two imagemagick `convert` commands?

1. `convert inverted.png -transparent white -negate temp.png`
2. `convert standard.png temp.png -composite final.png`

I can't figure out the syntax, though I'm sure I'll kick myself when I see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

First, you can load the inverted image first and negate it, then load the second and swap the order:

```
convert inverted.png -transparent white -negate standard.png +swap -composite result.png
```

Or, you can load them in the correct order, but use parentheses to ensure only the second is negated:

```
convert standard.png                             \
   \( inverted.png -transparent white -negate \) \
   -composite result.png
```

---

By the way, this is old v6 syntax, you should be using v7 by now which would be:

```
magick inverted.png -transparent white -negate standard.png +swap -composite result.png
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll check my tools to see what's what, but my build system is a couple of years old at this point. I'll migrate things to v7 ASAP